# Deriving revocation_pubkey BOLT #3

Tags: lightning-network, ln-commitment-transaction

I'm trying to reproduce keys derivation for testing vectors in Bolt #03.
At the moment I'm can not reproduce the `local_revocation_pubkey`: `0212a140cd0c6539d07cd08dfe09984dec3251ea808b892efeac3ede9402bf2b19`

Which `revocation_basepoint` and `per_commitment_point` shall I use for the derivation (I know the formula and have tested it with the other example)?

There is a description how to derive another `revocation_pubkey` `0x02916e326636d19c33f13e8c0c3a03dd157f332f3e99c317c141dd865eb01f8ff0`, but not the one used in the first commitment.

Could it be that the values of `revocation_basepoint` and `per_commitment_point` needed for derivation of `0212a140cd0c6539d07cd08dfe09984dec3251ea808b892efeac3ede9402bf2b19` are not included in the testing vectors?

Comment: BOLT3 describes how to derive it already, could you add more details to your question such as what you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Hello Pawel, could you please _edit your question post_ to provide more information instead of posting comments?

Comment: When you repeat the description how to derive the second `revocation_pubkey`, does your method reproduce the described results?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce with my code revocation_pubkey 0x02916e326636d19c33f13e8c0c3a03dd157f332f3e99c317c141dd865eb01f8ff0. But this key is not used in transactions examples, the revocation_pubkey that used in transaction examples is 0212a140cd0c6539d07cd08dfe09984dec3251ea808b892efeac3ede9402bf2b19. My goal was just to manually recreate all transactions in testing vector, but I believe revocation_basepoint and per_commitment_point are not included in testing vectors